# Grails - migrating from the resources to the asset-pipeline plugin

Tags: grails, asset-pipeline

I've been trying to install the *angularjs/restangular* js libraries in my Grails app based on a chapter in [Grails In Action](http://www.manning.com/gsmith2/). The problem is that the code in this book uses the *resources* plugin which has been replaced in the version of Grails I'm using (2.4) by the *asset-pipeline* plugin.

I've tried to implementing the book code using [the official documentation](http://grails.github.io/grails-doc/2.4.x/guide/single.html#resources)  as a guide, but the required javascript is not getting included in my gsp files. Also, references to `<r:layoutResources/>` and `<r:require module="core"/>` in my gsp files, are being highlighted as "unknown tags" in the GGTS editor.

Can anyone advise on where I've gone wrong migrating from the *resources* plugin to the *asset-pipeline*? Specifically I have copied the following *js libraries* into my web-app/js folder:

[image]

And I want to define dependencies between those modules and so I have created the following `conf\ApplicationResources.groovy`:

```
modules = {

    angularjs {
        resource url:'js/angular-1.3.15.js', disposition: 'head'
    }

    restangular {
        dependsOn 'angularjs'
        resource url:'js/restangular-1.4.0.js'
    }

    lodashjs {
        resource url:'js/lodash-3.6.0.js'
    }

    core {
        dependsOn 'restangular, lodashjs'
        resource url:'/js/custom.js'
    }
}
```

And `views\layout\main.gsp` contains:

```
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
    <title><g:layoutTitle default="Grails"/></title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="${assetPath(src: 'favicon.ico')}" type="image/x-icon">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="${assetPath(src: 'apple-touch-icon.png')}">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="114x114" href="${assetPath(src: 'apple-touch-icon-retina.png')}">
      <asset:stylesheet src="application.css"/>
    <asset:javascript src="application.js"/>
    <g:layoutHead/>
    <r:layoutResources/> <-- why is this highlighted as 'unknown'?
</head>
```

And `views\post\singlepage.gsp`:

```
<head>
    <title>Timeline for ${ user.userid }</title>
    <meta name="layout" content="main"/>
    <content tag="htmlAttrs">ng-app="testsparestang"</content>
    <r:require module="core"/> <-- again, this is unknown!
</head>
```

Comment: asset-pipeline has been replaced as the default. You can always just remove it and use the resources plugin instead.

Comment: Thanks, but I'd like to keep using asset-pipeline if possible. I'm guessing it must be better than the resources plugin (somehow?).

Comment: I'm not convinced it is in every case. For a single page javascript-heavy design, I get it. For your typical refresh response application, I see no huge benefit and it is more limited than resources on how you can manage your dependencies.

Comment: the main advantage of the asset pipeline plugin, is that every js / css file is copied to the the client on every request. It seems as a main disadvantage at first glance, but the http caching model that comes into play and is used by asset-pipeline in production will reduce the amount of traffic over time. You don't need `ApplicationResources.groovy` (because there are no dependencies anymore) and `r:*`, since only necessary with the resource plugin. Additionally your assets go to `grails-app/assets` (see [asset-pipeline docs](https://grails.org/plugin/asset-pipeline))

Comment: I see, thanks Mario David. That explains a lot then. The official documentation is misleading imo. It specifically talks about using a r:require tags and an application resources file in the asset-pipeline section.

Comment: @Gregg I think you're mistaken. The resources plugin was replaced by asset-pipeline some time around 2.4.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use resource plugin please comment the asset-pipeline plugin code from your BuildConfig.groovy file.
And if you want to use asset-pipeline then just comment the resources plugin from the BuildConfig.groovy.
Now see to it that you remove the  tag from your layout as this will work only with resources plugin and is not required with asset-pipeline.
Also the  tag is from resources plugin. So change it as per the asset-pipeline